# Seekbar progress drawable show wrong issue when its progess value is zero

Tags: android, layout, seekbar

I am new in android platform. I am trying to develop the custom seek bar using .9 path image and xml.I created almost but my problem is occurs when seekbar is appear first time when activity start its show wrong progress level when my progess level is define 0 in xml. you check out image

[image]

Here my xml file code

```
        <Seekbar
            android:id="@+id/Slider1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="0"
            android:splitTrack="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green_seekbar"
            android:thumb="@drawable/slidercontralbt2" />
```

green_seekbar.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <nine-patch
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/sb"
        android:dither="true"
     />
</item>
 <item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/green_seekbar_progress"
/>
```

green_seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item >
  <clip>
    <nine-patch
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/green"
        android:dither="true"
     />
    </clip>  
  </item>
```

Comment: Hello please give your some attention for new user..

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh for edited and formatting question my

Comment: could you try to set in `onCreate` as `0` to progress bar

Comment: yes i will try in code and xml both side

Comment: It happened only first time when i change the seek bar value it working fine.

Comment: So set it onCreate programatically to 0

Comment: I will try onCreate set seekbar value 0 but nothing happned

Comment: Hello please help i stuck these problem last 48 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally The reach to the solution. Put the below code in the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .....
    .....
    Slider1.setProgress(0);
    Slider1.invalidate();

}
```